# Need help to download multiple images in zip file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jszip

I have code that is working according to jszip 2x but now showing error "This method has been removed in JSZip 3.0, please check the upgrade guide.". I have already checked upgraded guide but my code is still not working. I Need help to download multiple images in zip file in angularjs. Thanks in advance.

```
  var zip = new JSZip();
            var count = 0;
            var zipFilename = "zipFilename.zip";
            var urls = [
                'http://54.190.15.249/photo/1476967612xyKgSfAlgHEHSt49LfnmvVw3MWTVq4.png',
                'http://54.190.15.249/photo/1476967612xyKgSfAlgHEHSt49LfnmvVw3MWTVq4.png',
                'http://54.190.15.249/photo/1476967612xyKgSfAlgHEHSt49LfnmvVw3MWTVq4.png'
            ];

            urls.forEach(function(url){
                var filename = "filename";
                // loading a file and add it in a zip file
                JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
                    if(err) {
                        throw err; // or handle the error
                    }
                    zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
                    count++;
                    if (count == urls.length) {
                        var zipFile = zip.generate({type: "blob"});
                        saveAs(zipFile, zipFilename);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: This is **not** a "write the code for me" service ...

Comment: Have you... checked the upgrade guide?

Comment: Haha. No.......

Comment: @TZHX Yes I have checked, but enable to understand it thats why asked for help here

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `zip.generate`... which has been removed in JSZip v3. Like says the [upgrade guide](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/upgrade_guide.html), you need to use [`generateAsync`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html) which returns a promise.

In your case, you can write a function to wrap `JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent` and return a promise of the result (from [here](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/blob/v3.1.3/documentation/examples/downloader.js#L55)):

```
/**
 * Fetch the content and return the associated promise.
 * @param {String} url the url of the content to fetch.
 * @return {Promise} the promise containing the data.
 */
function urlToPromise(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then, for each url, transform it to a promise of the downloaded content and add it to your zip object (like [here](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/blob/v3.1.3/documentation/examples/downloader.js#L79)):

```
urls.forEach(function(url){
  var filename = url.replace(/.*\//g, "");
  zip.file(filename, urlToPromise(url), {binary:true});
}
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function (zipFile) {
  saveAs(zipFile, zipFilename);
});
```

See the full example [here](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/downloader.html).